# Managing tunneled SSH ports in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, tunnel

I usually SSH into a cluster of machines and tunnel a large number of ports to the `localhost` for various web browser based services.

However, the more the number of ports increases, the harder it becomes remembering all the tunnels, especially when many of the ports are standard 80 or 8080 on different machines, and become (for example) 180, 28080 on my `localhost`.

What are the best tools for working in such situations? Is there a way to encode certain URLs so they are easier to remember names, i.e., `localhost:28888` --> `service_1.com`

Comment: I can only think of NAT-ing via iptables. For an example: https://askubuntu.com/a/936167 However, there must be other useful tools for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than port forwarding, have you considered using ssh as a SOCKS proxy, so the local web browser could access those services directly?  This, of course, depends on the ssh client you're using, but openssh supports it with the `-D` flag, and I believe PuTTY supports it as well.

Then in the networking of your browser, you'll point its SOCKS proxy that the port you setup (and potentially allow DNS through it too if you desire), then the browser can just go to those servers as though it were being run from the landing machine of your ssh client.

Often when I'm doing stuff like this I'll use 2 browsers and have 1 of them setup for the proxy and 1 that I leave unchanged so I can browse as normal from my local machine.  Say, using Firefox for through-the-proxy-browsing and Chrome without the proxy.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! PuTTY does indeed support it, and with modifying the ``hosts`` file this gets pretty much exactly what I was hoping for! Strange that this got downvotes, though.